# How to format int to price format in SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I select the price 1000000 and I need to format it to $1,000,000. How can I do that in SQL?

Answer (score 4):

To format with commas, you can use [`CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) with a style of `1`:

```
declare @money money = 1000000

select '$' + convert(varchar, @money, 1)
```

will produce `$1,000,000.00`

If you want to remove the last 3 characters:

```
select '$' + left(convert(varchar, @money, 1), charindex('.', convert(varchar, @money, 1)) - 1)
```

and if you want to round rather than truncate:

```
select '$' + left(convert(varchar, @money + $0.50, 1), charindex('.', convert(varchar, @money, 1)) - 1)
```

Comment: Could someone create a custom function to format numbers? See also: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/14/sql-server-get-date-time-in-any-format-udf-user-defined-functions/

Comment: Ah - I didn't notice the datatype 'money' - you need to make sure you convert to money, first (baby)! (From another answer: SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CAST(987654321 AS money), 1))

Comment: Simplest formatting for 2008, I had to edit an old database with this formatting

Answer (score 2):

**Creating Function:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[f_FormatMoneyValue]
(
    @MoneyValue   money
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS

BEGIN
    RETURN cast(@MoneyValue as numeric(36,2))
END
```

**Using in Select Query:**

```
Select dbo.f_FormatMoneyValue(isnull(SalesPrice,0))SalesPrice from SalesOrder
```

**Output:**

100.00

**Formatting Money Value with '$' sign:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[f_FormatMoneyWithDollar]
(
    @MoneyValue  money
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS

BEGIN
   RETURN '$' + convert(varchar, @MoneyValue, 1)
END
```

**Output:**

$100.00

**Note:** The above sample is for the money field. You can modify this function according to your needs
Hope this helps you..! :D

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FORMAT(price, 'C2', 'en-us')
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27812013)

Comment: @DawidRutkowski please explain - i tested it and it formats 1000000 as $1,000,000.00 - using C0 instead of C2 formats it without the decimal.  Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server money datatype is just decimal(10, 4). To my knowledge there is no datatype that will present the way you want.

Adding the dollar sign and commas is something that should belong in the application logic, but if you really must do it through a database object consider adding the dollar sign, and commas every three characters (after the decimal point). In other words, you'll have to convert the int to varchar and do string manipulation.

Comment: "Commafying" a number-string is trickier that you might imagine ;-)

Comment: So my question was how to separate with comma ... - string format

Answer (score 0):

It depends, however, there's no simple way to do it in standard SQL specs(SQL-92, SQL-2003, etc.).

For PostgreSQL PL/pgSQL and Oracle PL/SQL, you can use `to_char` to format numbers:

```
select to_char(1234567.123, 'FM$999,999,999.99')
```

Which gives output:

```
$1,234,567.12
```

See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7/static/functions2976.htm

Comment: There's no point giving an answer using the `to_char` function which is not available in SQL Server. The question was tagged with the DB they are using.